# Water in house to heat and cool?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, cooling

In the summer, when it reaches 27c during the day I want it to be colder, and when it reaches 15c at night I want it to be warmer.

Is it possible to do some of this heating and cooling with water (storage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is, and the easiest but not very attractive method involves simply placing many 55-gallon sealed drums full of water inside your home. They will soak up heat in the daytime and release it at night. Systems like this are called *passive solar* and lots of material has been written about them in the last 50 years. .

Less ugly and more efficient systems use pumps to move hot or cold water through pipes inside your house and specially-designed heat collectors on the roof to catch the sun's heat and get it into the water, after which it is stored for night time use in an insulated tank.

The most popular systems use electric machines called *heat pumps* to draw heat out of your house and dump it into water that is pumped up out of a nearby well. This furnishes cooling when it's hot. Then, to provide heat when it's cold, the system is run in reverse to extract heat from well water and move it into your house. In both cases, the "used" water is pumped back down into a second well near the first. In a sense, you are using the ground water under your home as a sort of heating and cooling storage reservoir, instead of filling your house with barrels of water. Heat pumps also have the great advantage of letting you choose exactly what temperature you want the house to be at both day and night!

Answer (score 1):

If there is an insulated container over the roof, between the water box and the outlets, the water is gradually heated during the day, and gradually cooled during the night. The temperature differences become smaller.